# Facebook returns null objects

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am new in android programming. I have first time get data from Facebook .But if I login and wait for about 2-3 minutes, the Object returns null. I am using Facebook class not Facebook SDK and problem in doinbackground() method so post execute() method not execute.so any one tell me what is wrong in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Next Activity.java

```
 package com.example.facebookdemo;


 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.MalformedURLException;
  import java.util.ArrayList;

 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.app.Dialog;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.Facebook.Facebook;
 import com.Facebook.FacebookError; 
 import com.Facebook.Util;
 import com.example.adapter.CustomBaseAdapter;
 import com.example.model.RowItems;

 public class NextActivity extends Activity{

ListView lv;
Facebook mFacebook;
//AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
ProgressDialog mProgress;
String postId,response,messages;
ArrayList<RowItems> results ;
String msg;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    mFacebook = new Facebook(MainActivity.APP_ID);
    String token = mFacebook.getAccessToken();
    results=new ArrayList<RowItems>();
    new doInBackground().execute();

}

public class doInBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

   @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(NextActivity.this, "Facebook Friends",
                "Fetching Data", true, true);
    }; 

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        getSearchResults();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        mProgress.dismiss();
        lv.setAdapter(new CustomBaseAdapter(NextActivity.this,results));
    }

}



private void getSearchResults(){

     Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
     parameters.putString("message", msg);
     try {
         String response = mFacebook.request("me?fields=home.limit(10)", parameters,
                 "GET");
         System.out.println(response);

            JSONObject jsonObject=null;

            try {
                jsonObject = Util.parseJson(response);
                Log.i("json Response", jsonObject.toString());
            } catch (FacebookError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JSONArray ja= jsonObject.getJSONObject("home").getJSONArray("data");
                for(int i=0;i<=ja.length();i++){
                JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                 RowItems items=new RowItems();
                 postId = jo.getString("id");

                JSONObject jo1 = jo.getJSONObject("from");
                String userProfileID = jo1.getString("id");
                String name = jo1.getString("name");
                 messages = jo.getString("message");

                if (userProfileID.equals(name)) {
                    items.setName(name);            
                    } else if (userProfileID.equals(messages)) {
                     items.setMessages(messages);

                }
                //list_ProfilePic.add("http://graph.facebook.com/"+userProfileID+"/picture?type=large");
                 results.add(items);
                }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }


   }
}
```

here is my json

```
    {
"home": {
"data": [
  {
    "id": "514806045331953_533082596837631", 
    "from": {
      "name": "Yunus Bobotohpersib Jurigpersibcikampekbarat", 
      "id": "514806045331953"
    }, 
    "message": "Off hela arek dahar :)\n\n#freeadySuee", 
    "actions": [
      {
        "name": "Comment", 
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/514806045331953/posts/533082596837631"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "Like", 
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/514806045331953/posts/533082596837631"
      }
    ], 
    "privacy": {
      "value": ""
    }, 
    "type": "status", 
    "status_type": "mobile_status_update", 
    "application": {
      "name": "Facebook for Every Phone", 
      "id": "139682082719810"
    }, 
    "created_time": "2014-09-06T03:42:15+0000", 
    "updated_time": "2014-09-06T03:42:15+0000", 
    "likes": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "541839042584928", 
          "name": "Libra Gembelgembelsoten Anakdongo"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "1478461745742208", 
          "name": "Neng Ikha"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "611873252262908", 
          "name": "R'agil Putra"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "1661741794050418", 
          "name": "Norma C'nax Duchiietea GhajaNhimasta"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "506133499521977", 
          "name": "Wina Cuttegirl"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "1462738317325223", 
          "name": "Jamal S'boedakholigancikampek"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "656484581115919", 
          "name": "Mien Putrii Laviigne"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "427256690746224", 
          "name": "Puspa Echa Andani"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "843251385685549", 
          "name": "Imam Joe"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "1494528947454941", 
          "name": "Nani Maryani"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "245675808975948", 
          "name": "Zhuan Fals Duameniitsepuluhdetik"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "270769306466270", 
          "name": "Siti Munajah"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "286452664887250", 
          "name": "Rendi Syahputra"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "332245536951320", 
          "name": "Yuyun Latifahc"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "493466714113744", 
          "name": "Cacing Uwiss Warass"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "1469440296660772", 
          "name": "Syaie Whardhanie"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "1457472927860947", 
          "name": "Imma Nur Adima"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "662163223890967", 
          "name": "Indah Fije"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "296274043911531", 
          "name": "Rena C'cwcuttethea"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "329340663893934", 
          "name": "Aplez Sibocah Falsyangterlupakan"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "1451779098419632", 
          "name": "Radieth BomberMaungbiroe"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "627163187401324", 
          "name": "Mbi Semoks"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "708875802532701", 
          "name": "Gua TuchRespector Persibkabehdoeloer"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "348686475290235", 
          "name": "Rika Nur"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "1517480285132215", 
          "name": "Icha"
        }
      ], 
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "after": "MTUxNzQ4MDI4NTEzMjIxNQ==", 
          "before": "NTQxODM5MDQyNTg0OTI4"
        }, 
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/100004076851807_533082596837631/likes?         limit=25&after=MTUxNzQ4MDI4NTEzMjIxNQ=="
      }
    }
   }
```

Comment: what does getDataInList() returns ?

Comment: sorry not getdatainlist but problem is in getSearchResults().

Comment: when the compiler is in this line  System.out.println(response); you get null ?

Comment: I have also debug cursor execute response line after direct execute  catch ecxeption.

Answer (score 0):

try it this way

change this line :

```
mFacebook.request("me?fields=home.limit(10)", parameters,
                 "GET");
```

with this 2 lines :

```
Request request = mFacebook.request("me?fields=home.limit(10)", parameters,
                 "GET");
Response response = request.executeAnWait();
```